# How to set 'Version info' in Delphi XE7? [Delphi design issue]

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I just upgraded one of my projects from Delphi XE to XE7.
The version info for 'All platforms/All configurations' global target (should I call it 'base'?) was copied correctly from the old project.

> Company name: xxx
>   File version: 3.2.1
>   etc

However, when I checked the sub-targets (32 bit /release, 32 bit /debug, etc) they are all set to ''. So they don't copy/inherit the info from 'All platforms/All configurations'.

> Company name: ''
>   File version: 1.0.0
>   etc

How do I force the sub-targets to inherit from 'All platforms/All configurations'.

---

UPDATE: It seems to be a design issue with Delphi XE7. The sub-targets stay in sync as long as you DON'T edit them. A 'Sync sub-targets to main target' button is missing from that window. There is also a BUG close related to this (see my answer for details).

Comment: This is one of those areas where, in my view, you should not let the IDE get involved. Make building the version resource part of your build scripting.

Comment: The main reason why version information isn't in sync between differen platforms is becouse that would be counter intuitive. For instance imagine that you only make a code change in a platform specific unit. After doing this you would only need to recompile program for that specific platform but not for others. So now the version information between new executable and old ones that weren't recompiled will no longer be the same.

Comment: @SilverWarior-Then, in the first place, why are (and stay) the version numbers synchronized (before you edit them)? Also, let's suppose that I resynchronize the code and the version is the same on all platforms. At this moment I would have to manually update to version info in 6 places! They will never get resynchronized again.

Comment: There are many places in all the XE.. versions where I wish they would add a "Reset" or "Inherit" button or checkbox for this exact reason. The developer should have full control over that, and not rely on the IDE to decide for you.

Comment: Delphi 7 and XE are really stable/well built editions. XE7 seemed to to be the next stable editions. Unfortunately, is as unfinished and shabby as all the XE2+ editions. They hurried up to add new features (which is great) but totally forgot about the IDE itself. At it is Delphi is not quite RAD. I would call it more RADIYALE: Rapid Application Development If You Are Lucky Enough... (not to encounter a show-ending bug).

Comment: This is not a bug. Child settings just have a precedence over the parent when they are defined and as such should not be modified when you change the parent. So, buttons which @Jerry proposed would take place here in my view.

Comment: @TLama-That's what I proposed also.

Comment: It looks like it's behaving as designed, and it's always been this way. It was this way in XE too.

Comment: @JerryDodge there is open QC report "Provide mechanism for clearing all descendant build options" http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=109471

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right, behavior is "as designed" "Changes to All Configurations - All Platforms are not applied to all configurations/platforms" http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=99275

Comment: @Dalija Not only is it as designed, but thee design is sound

Comment: @David it is not that sound when so many people has issues with it... probably the biggest issue is that there is no indication that any of child settings is set when you change parent, and you can happily go on unknowing that you failed making changes.

Comment: @Dalija The feature is well designed and documented. Inheritance is the key. Imagine if it was done the other way. It would be a total nightmare. As is so often the case the way forward is to understand the software you use.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar-Related to your QC report: You can post your comment as  answer. This is what I need (and is missing from Delphi). I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Altar What exactly needs to change. Inheritance works as designed. And the design seems quite sound to me.

Comment: Sorry @David Hefferman etc, the very existence of the option "Auto Increment Build Number" seems to contradict that this is working as designed. When the build number gets incremented, it always breaks the inheritance of version information from All Configurations to Debug and Release. The fact that option is still around (and has been around much longer than the inheritance of build configurations), seems to indicate to me that this got just included by default in the record structure of all the other project options, and so got included in the inheritance process in the newer Delphi versions

Comment: Personally I want the version resource information in all my build configurations to always be synchronised, whether debug / release / 32 or 64 bit / different operating systems, and the build number to be auto incremented across all of those. Or, if not, then the inheritance must work per property, not just for the whole version resource e.g. setting the Company Name, Product and File version in the parent (all configurations), but the Product Name separately e.g. CoolDelphiApp for Windows, CoolDelphiApp for Mac OS etc.

Comment: If *"inheritance is key, and works as designed"*, then how do i use the inherited value? There exists a way to always *"use the inherited value"* on compiler options; but there is no such mechanism on "version info" or "application options".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **bug** in the IDE (Delphi XE7).

**How to reproduce:**

1. Set the main target to version 1.0.0.0.
   Save project.
   Restart IDE.
   All sub-targets are in sync.
2. Now open the DPR and edit anything in it. Save it. 
   Set the main target to version 2.0.0.0.
   Save project.
   Restart IDE.
   The current sub-target (the one that was active while you edited the DPR file) is not in sync anymore. It will get stuck to 1.0.0.0

**Solution:**
Close the project in IDE. Open the DPROJ file in a text editor (not in IDE!) and deleted the entries containing the wrong version info, for ex. where VerInfo_MajorVer=1 instead of 2.

Comment: It seems this is still there in Delphi Berlin. Someone can confirm?

Comment: This bug also exists in XE6. This fix also works for XE6.

Comment: Bug still there in Delphi Sydney.  After opening the Project options and changing the version in the Global branch, the current branch will be wrong.